# Story that has a man with a Gryphon's head

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a fantasy story I read several years back. I can't remember much about it and I hope I'm not crossing stories.

I remember there was a city, possibly a port city. The leader was a warrior with a man's body, but he had the head of a gryphon. I'm pretty sure he could speak normally. The main characters part leaves out of the city and I'm pretty sure they're transporting a person or animal in a caravan. It/They were either in a cage or weren't allowed out of the wagon.

They caravan ended up going to take what they were carrying to some community in the woods. I think people there lived in houses built into trees or maybe the just blended into the forest. Either way, it was nature-y. I think I remember that one of the main characters was wandering off by themselves and a small drake or dragon came out. They thought it was attacking, but a person who lived there said it just wanted to play and it wasn't one of the dangerous dragons that had human intelligence, but a dumb animal cousin.

Again, I hope I'm not mixing stories and I main wanted to know about the gryphon headed guy. I seem to remember that assassins tried to take him out, possibly because of what was being transported and he ended up killing them.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Update: (5/25/16)

Hey everyone, I keep searching google for anything I can remember. I saw a cover called 'Ice Dragon' by Richard A. Knaack. It seems familiar, but I don't have access to a copy. Does anyone know if this could be the book? Thanks.

Comment: I wonder how he knew he has the head of a griffin rather than the head of an eagle?

Comment: I feel like gryphon was part of his name or title. Also, it sounds cooler. If I had a bird's head I'd definitely go with gryphon over any other bird head.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno why centaurs don't all say they have the back half of a unicorn. ;)

Comment: @Paul And why not the head of a hippogryph?

Comment: "Grinzleville" has an eagle-headed person. Could it be that?

Comment: I always picture a hippo when I hear hippogryph. It always takes a second of mental adjustment to get the picture right.

Comment: @Jonah, sorry, but I've never heard of "Grinzleville" I did a search and nothing about it looked familiar.

Comment: As per your comment on the Dragonrealm books, there is a character named "The Gryphon" (http://dragonrealm.wikia.com/wiki/The_Gryphon) who does appear to have the right sort of head. Recently, the 14th book, *The Gryphon Mage*, is apparently about one of his descendents.

Comment: And the first three books include The Gryphon as a character although most of the focus on him is in the third book. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6578970-legends-of-the-dragonrealm-vol-i

Comment: Google Books has an excerpt available: https://books.google.com/books?id=5LTvZyu-EY8C&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=dragon+realm+%22the+gryphon%22&source=bl&ots=k3Snz5V_ef&sig=ZV5dvs_fbtXknWPBq9tfXwBpOUo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNiJqzrvXMAhWEiywKHeCcASwQ6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=dragon%20realm%20%22the%20gryphon%22&f=false

Comment: I looked and bits and piece seem familiar, but I can't tell from that excerpt. I'll try to get my hands on a copy of the book and skim it to see if it's the right one.

Comment: I have a copy of the book coming in from the library. Hopefully, between the two of us, we can figure it out. :)

Comment: The book is a bit slow going for me, but at least among the first three books, it does not look like a match.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I know this is old, but reading the title, I just assumed it was the Knaak books.  There is a "nature house" in the books.  I'm pretty sure it was one or another of the early ones (meaning the 90s era books rather than the 2000s).  I'd guess perhaps Dragon Crown

Comment: @eshier: It's possible. I only got about halfway through the compiled version the library sent me before having to return it, and the only match I saw was that they had a figure named "The Gryphon" (with said head) and dragons existed in the setting.